# Inserting text to summernote from javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

So I've been trying to insert text into the summernote within a normal javascript function. I have a list of values that when clicked should append themselves into the actual text area. The functions are firing because I have messages being logged to the console when I click but for some reason nothing is still appending. Here is the function:

```
function appendListItem(ele){
    console.log("Clicked!");
    var id = $(ele).attr("id");
    console.log(typeof(id));
    console.log("ID:" + id);
    //var htmlStr = "<p>#"+id+"</p>";
    $(".summernote").summernote('code', id);
    console.log($("#summernote").summernote('code'));
}
```

Everything is working except for the 7th line, $(".summernote").summernote('code', id);. I've tried using 'insertText' as well in the summernote function. The id is a string. And I've tried passing in an html string as evidenced by the commented out line (Line 6). Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT 1:**

Here is my html as requested:

```
<body>
    <div><img src="./images/Logo.png" alt="Logo"  class="logo-center"></div>
    <div id="summernote"></div>
    <div class="checkList">
        <p id="checkTitle">CHECKLIST (<span id="fraction">0/5</span>)</p>
        <ul class="list-group" id="trigList">
            <li class='list-group-item'><a id='mood' onclick='appendListItem(this)'>Mood</a></li>
            <li class='list-group-item'><a id='phone' onclick='appendListItem(this)'>Phone</a></li>
            <li class='list-group-item'><a id='email' onclick='appendListItem(this)'>Email</a></li>
            <li class='list-group-item'><a id='lead' onclick='appendListItem(this)'>Lead</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="logNote();">Log Note</button></div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you show your html too?

Comment: @AndrewLohr Just did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have jQuery selectors mixed up. You have 1 Summernote so you can access it by using its ID `id="summernote"`

what you are currently doing, using this line `$(".summernote").summernote('code', id);`- is telling jQuery to get all elements that have a **class** of `summernote` due to the `.` selector in the beginning.

No elements in your html have a **class** of `summernote` so that is why its not working.

Change `$(".summernote").summernote('code', id);` to `$("#summernote").summernote('code', id);` and it should work. the `#` will get the element with `id="summernote"` which is your actual Summernote element.

Here is a full working example

```
<body>
    <div><img src="./images/Logo.png" alt="Logo"  class="logo-center"></div>
    <div id="summernote"></div>
    <div class="checkList">
        <p id="checkTitle">CHECKLIST (<span id="fraction">0/5</span>)</p>
        <ul class="list-group" id="trigList">
            <li class='list-group-item'><a id='mood' onclick='appendListItem(this)'>Mood</a></li>
            <li class='list-group-item'><a id='phone' onclick='appendListItem(this)'>Phone</a></li>
            <li class='list-group-item'><a id='email' onclick='appendListItem(this)'>Email</a></li>
            <li class='list-group-item'><a id='lead' onclick='appendListItem(this)'>Lead</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="logNote();">Log Note</button></div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#summernote').summernote();
    });
    function appendListItem(elem) {
      //var htmlStr = "<p>#"+id+"</p>";
      var id = $(elem).attr("id");
      console.log(id);
      $("#summernote").summernote('code', id);
      // use 'insertText' instead of 'code' to append the id instead
    }
  </script>
</body>
```